# Is celery following my rate limit properly?

Tags: python, django, celery, flower

I have a rate-limited task in Celery but the results as shown in Flower make it appear as though it is processing a bunch of tasks right away and then obeying the rate limit. Why is this happening? Is there something I need to do to make sure that it obeys the rate limit from the start?

```
@shared_task(rate_limit="4/m")
    def my_task(a,b):
        ...
```

...

```
my_task.apply_async((x, y,),)
```

[image: succeeded tasks]

[image: steps]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have more than one worker consuming my_task? If so your rate limit will not be taken into effect since celery rate limits are *per worker* ([docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.rate_limit)). To get around this you'll need to route my_task to a queue that has only one worker consuming from it. See [routing docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#manual-routing).

Comment: good call, looks like I had a worker that did not shut down properly. I missed this error message `UserWarning: A node named celery@XXXX-MacBook-Pro.local is already using this process mailbox!`